# html video does not open all videos

Tags: html, video

i've a code of html video but it does not open all devices , how could i make it for all videos?

```
$files = glob("www/$lnk/*.{mp4,flv,mkv,avi,rmvb,MP4,FLV,MKV,AVI‬‬,RMVB}", GLOB_BRACE);
sort($files);
$S = '"';
$i = -1;
$first = basename($files[0]);
foreach ($files as $filename) {
 $vName = basename($filename);
 $fName = basename($filename,'.mp4');
 $fName = basename($fName,'.flv');
  $fName = basename($filename,'.avi');
 $fName = basename($filename,'.MP4');
 $fName = basename($fName,'.FLV');
 $i++;

 echo"
 <div onclick=$S chkListImg('$i'); $('#videoCont').html('<video autoplay controls width=100% height=100% src=www/$lnk/$vName/></video>'); $('.downBtn').attr('id','$vName'); $S id='playListImg' class='$vName' name='playListImg' title='$fName'>
 <img name='topicListImg' border='0' src='pictures/$img' style='width:100%; height:100%; box-sizing:border-box; border:0px solid #ff1300;' />
 </div>
 ";

}
```

i've tried to add new things for {mp4,flv,mkv,avi,rmvb,MP4,FLV,MKV,AVI‬‬,RMVB} but it also did not work!

Comment: on what kind of devices do you mean?

Comment: i want it to support all videos mp3 , mkv , etc...

Answer (score 1):

HTML 5 supports mp4, webm, ogg formats cover all devices..

You can use this code like this to supports as,

```
if(this.video.canPlayType("video/mp4")){
  this.video.src="video/filename.mp4";

}else if(this.video.canPlayType("video/webm")){
  this.video.src="video/filename.webm";

}else{
  this.video.src="video/filename.ogg";
}
```

You can refer W3schools for more on this video etc.,

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_met_canplaytype.asp

Comment: i want it to support mkv and others too not only those

Comment: you have to convert these available formats, to view in html 5.. The other file types will not support.. If you want to try, have to use means need a media codecs to view the other types. Use embed or object code to view these formats.

Answer (score -1):

```
function get_mime_Type($filename) {
      $MimeArray = array(
         "rmvb" => "application/vnd.rn-realmedia-vbr",
         "m3u8" => "application/x-mpegurl",
         "ts" => "video/MP2T",
         "avi" => "video/x-msvideo",
         "wmv" => "video/x-ms-wmv",
         "3gp" => "video/3gpp",
         "flv" => "video/x-flv",
         "mp4" => "video/mp4",
         "mpeg" => "video/mpeg",
         "mpg" => "video/mpeg",
         "mpe" => "video/mpeg",
         "qt" => "video/quicktime",
         "mov" => "video/quicktime",
         "mxu" => "video/vnd.mpegurl",
         // "mkv" => "video/mkv",
         "mkv" => "video/x-matroska; codecs='theora, vorbis'",
         "ts" => "video/webm",
         // "ts" => "video/MP2T",
         "avi" => "video/x-msvideo",
         "movie" => "video/x-sgi-movie"
      );
      // get base name of the filename provided by user
      $filename = basename($filename);

      // break file into parts seperated by .
      $filename = explode('.', $filename);

      // take the last part of the file to get the file extension
      $filename = $filename[count($filename)-1];

      // find mime type
      return $MimeArray[$filename];
   }

$files = glob("www/$lnk/*.{mp4,flv,mkv,avi,rmvb}", GLOB_BRACE);
sort($files);
$S = '"';
$i = -1;
$first = basename($files[0]);
foreach ($files as $filename) {
 $vName = basename($filename);

$finfo = pathinfo($vName);
$file_name =  basename($vName,'.'.$finfo['extension']);
$file_name =  str_replace("-", " " ,$file_name);
$file_name =  str_replace("_", " " ,$file_name);
$file_name =  str_replace(".", " " ,$file_name);
 // $fName = basename($filename,'.mp4');
 // $fName = basename($fName,'.flv');
 // $fName = basename($filename,'.AVI‬‬');
 // $fName = basename($fName,'.avi');
 // $fName = basename($filename,'.MP4');
 // $fName = basename($fName,'.FLV');
 $i++;
$gt_type=get_mime_Type($vName);
```

i've got this but it still does not support everything